PDO_ODBC not returing same data as odbc_* functions
I'm not able to return same data with PDO functions and with ODBC_* functions. With the same driver.
The database is SAP HANA.
Code:
        $driver = 'HDBODBC';
        $host = "XX.XX.XX.XX:30015";
        $db_name = "MY_DATABASE";
        $username = "XXX";
        $password = "XXXX";
        $conn = odbc_connect("Driver=$driver;ServerNode=$host;Database=$db_name;", $username, $password, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

        $params = [
            'Belkin',
            '',
            '',
            'AL'
        ];
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM "MY_DATABASE"."PRODUCT" (%s%s%s) LIMIT 10';
        $sql = sprintf($sql,"'",implode("','",$params),"'");

        $result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

        while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
            dump($row);
            break;
        }

        $dsn = "odbc:Driver=$driver;ServerNode=$host;Database=$db_name";


        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        dump($result[0]);

First dump returns:

Second dump returns:

